# Meanings and roles of 要 inside 信用卡比现金要方便多了。

Tags: grammar, particles

> 信用卡比现金要方便多了。

I think that 要 can be removed from the above sentence to convey the same meaning of the original sentence.

I looked up for several online dictionaries but still haven't got the meaning(s) of 要 which is used here.

BTW can I interpret 了 which is used here is of "太 〜 了"? I mean that 方便多了 is an abbreviation of "方便太多了"

Comment: I don't know which dictionaries have you checked. But its meaning is 'relatively ... compared to something'(see e.g. the 10th meaning in [this page](https://hanyu.baidu.com/zici/s?from=aladdin&query=%E8%A6%81&srcid=51368&wd=%E8%A6%81) ). This usage is quite standard as you can find in any dictionaries.

Comment: I've been mostly using eng-to-chn or chn-to-eng dictionaries. I think I should start using a chn-to-chn dictionary from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

要 here is for emphasis, it can be removed and the sentence's meaning wouldn't change.

- 信用卡比现金方便多了 = Credit cards are more convenient than cash
- 信用卡比现金[要]方便多了 = Credit cards are [way] more convenient than cash

太 too is for emphasis here

- 方便多了 = much more convenient
- 方便[太]多了 = [too] much more convenient

Answer (score 0):

There's more sentences that has the same meaning, for example:
[要]和现金比，信用卡[可]方便多了。
和现金比，信用卡[可要]方便多了。

note that the [要] in the 1st sentence means 'if' (要是 or 如果 or 若论), and 2nd's [要] and another [可]s are both for emphasis. You can remove them:
和现金比，信用卡方便[多了]。

If you also remove [多了], then the sentence becomes more affirmative:
和现金比，信用卡方便。

Or say it affirmative like this:
信用卡[要]比现金方便。

The original sentence you write here is more emotional:
信用卡比现金[要]方便多了。